# C - passing argument 1 of 'strcmp' makes pointer from integer without a cast

Tags: c, linked-list, strcmp

My function searchlist asks the user enter a student ID and lists that student ID and name. 
Here is my struct:

```
struct student {
    int ID;
    char name[40];
    struct student *next;
};
typedef struct student Student;
```

Here is my function:

```
void searchlist(Student *SLIST){
    Student *currentstudent = SLIST;
    char str[10], str2[10];

    printf("Enter a student ID: ");
    while(currentstudent != NULL){
        scanf("%d", &str);
        if(strcmp(str, (char)currentstudent->ID) == 0){
            printf("ID#: %d Name: %s", currentstudent->ID, currentstudent->name);
        }
    }
}
```

However, when I try compiling, it gives me a warning: passing argument 1 of 'strcmp' makes pointer from integer without a cast

Comment: Please ignore str2[10]. forgot to take that part out.

Comment: What are you trying to compare? Because it looks like you're trying to compare the value of a string (char[]) with a char, not another string ...

Answer (score 4):

The `strcmp` signature looks like this:

```
int strcmp(const char *s1, const char *s2);
```

I.e. the second parameter must be of type `const char*`. But you're giving it a `char`. Hence the error message you're getting (`char` is an "integer" type).

---

Also, `scanf("%d", &str);` requests `scanf` to read an integer and store it to `str`. But `str` is not an integer type. (This would've been caught by the compiler if you had compilation warnings enabled.)

---

You need something like this:

```
printf("Enter a student ID: ");
int givenID;
scanf("%d", &givenID); // read integer input to integer variable

while(currentstudent != NULL) {
    if(currentstudent->ID == givenID) { // check whether this user has the ID entered by the user
        printf("ID#: %d Name: %s", currentstudent->ID, currentstudent->name);
        break; // we found what we were looking for, stop the loop
    }
    currentstudent = currentstudent->next; // move on to the next student in the list
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You're not passing the right types of variable to these functions

```
    scanf("%d", &str);
```

This is expecting str to be an `int` but it's a string.

```
    if(strcmp(str, (char)currentstudent->ID) == 0){
```

This is expecting two strings (either `char *` or `char[]`) but the second parameter is an `int` and you're casting it to a `char`.

Since you're reading in an `int` and wanting to compare it to an `int` why not write it like this:

```
int in_id;
scanf("%d",&in_id);
if(in_id == currentstudent->ID) {
```